# How to ensure that a composite locator respects the settings of the component locators?

Tags: arcpy, geocoding, composite

This question is asked and answered for the benefit of anyone else who may struggle with this specific scenario.

Background: Two existing locators, each configured to write a Reference ID for matches. Using ArcCatalog or arcpy, created a composite locator from two individual locators.

Geocoding from within ArcMap, there is a dialogue that allows the user to specify to write the Reference ID. This setting is independent of the component locators. This setting appears to exist within the properties of the composite locator in ArcCatalog. However, one cannot modify the setting (annoying).

Geocoding using arcpy (GeocodeAddresses_geocoding), found that the Reference ID setting was not respected, and no Ref_ID field was in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The locator properties file (.loc) is a text file. Edit the .loc file of the composite locator to change WriteReferenceIDField = FALSE to WriteReferenceIDField = TRUE. Save the file and run the process again. Now, the Reference ID (Ref_ID) is included in the output.

[@amball](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30756/amball) provided the [hint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111828/41185) about the nature of the .loc file.